# SPF record is hard failing

Tags: dns, spf

I'm trying to get an [SPF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework) record set up on our domain, but it just seems to be get confused.

The domain is `letterpart.com` and the mail server is `mail.letterpart.com`. We send all of our emails from an [Exchange Server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Exchange_Server) at `mail.letterpart.com`, either directly or via [Perl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl) scripts that forward to the Exchange server. This is our only server and deals with incoming and outgoing mails.

We originally had

```
v=spf1 mx a:mail.letterpart.com a:cmail1.com ~all
```

which includes our mail server and that of [Campaign Monitor](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/) which we sometimes use to send out marketing emails.

This, though, was giving us a soft fail:

```
Recipient address rejected: SPF Tests: Mail-From Result="softfail": Mail From="*****@letterpart.com" HELO name="mail.letterpart.com" HELO Result="none" Remote IP="94.72.251.210">
```

I spoke to our [ISP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_service_provider), [KCOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KCOM_Group), and they came back with this reply:

> I have checked the existing SPF record and found a possible cause of
>   your "softfail". The "all" mechanism was prefixed with a "~" which
>   gives a soft fail. I have changed the records "all" section to "-all"
>   which should produce a fail.

Now, when I send mail from [Outlook](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Outlook), I get a hard fail:

```
spf-test@openspf.net on 22/06/2012 09:47
  You do not have permission to send to this recipient.  For assistance, contact your system administrator.
  <mail.letterpart.com #5.7.1 smtp;550 5.7.1 <spf-test@openspf.net>: Recipient address rejected: SPF Tests: Mail-From Result="fail": Mail From="*****@letterpart.com" HELO name="mail.letterpart.com" HELO Result="none" Remote IP="94.72.251.210">
```

I went back to our ISP and said that the change they made had indeed changed our soft fail into a hard fail, so can they now change it so we don't fail at all.

His reply was that this record is correct and that it shows that emails not coming from our domain will fail. I pointed out that the test I am sending was coming from our domain, and he just sent me a reference to *[SPF Record Syntax](http://www.openspf.org/SPF_Record_Syntax)* which is the same site I am testing the spf-test@openspf.net email on.

Have I completely got the wrong end of the stick when it comes to these records? I thought the idea was not to fail at all when sending from our domain.

Now. Our MX record shows the following:

```
mail.letterpart.com   94.72.251.212
```

But the SPF test email is showing the IP address as 94.72.251.210, and when I look at a header of an email sent from letterpart.com, it does indeed show it as coming from .210:

```
for *****@digitalessence.net; Fri, 22 Jun 2012 11:03:06 +0100
Received: from [94.72.251.210] (helo=mail.letterpart.com)
```

`94.72.251.210` is the Wan1 interface on our Firewall. Should I add an IP address to the SPF or a range?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking over your [SPF records](https://www.unlocktheinbox.com/resources/spfrecords/). It's listed as

```
v=spf1 ip4:94.72.251.210 a:cmail1.com ~all
```

It should look something like:

```
v=spf1 mx a ip4:94.72.251.210 a:cmail1.com ~all
```

Which will mean all the MX and A records for the current domain are valid.  I really don't understand why your have a PTR set up for `94.72.251.210` back to mail letterpart.com, when mail.letterpart.com points to `94.72.251.212`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it sounds like you answered your own question - you should add `94.72.251.210` to your SPF record if that is where your emails are sent from (as far the outside world is concerned).

That's the easy way. The harder solution is to figure out why your mail server winds up sending from that IP address and correct the firewall rules so that mail emerges from your network on the IP address associated with the mail server's name. This seems more correct and might have other benefits - your mail headers look "forged" if they use a name that's different from the actual IP address they come from.